# How to lock some rows in PostgreSQL when updating and let others to read?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I want to update some rows in a table, and I want to lock them so other processes don't update them as well at the same time. But I'd like other processes to read them.

The way I'm trying to accomplish it is like this:

```
MyTable.where(mycolumn: "some value").lock(true).update_all(mycolumn: "other value")
```

I think that `lock(true)` is locking the selected rows (it's what the documentation says), but I don't know if they are available for other selects at the same time. So I think I should force a "SHARE MODE".

I'm trying this:

```
MyTable.where(mycolumn: "some value").lock("LOCK IN SHARE MODE").update_all(mycolumn: "other value")
```

But it raises this error:

```
STATEMENT:  SELECT  "my_table".* FROM "my_table"  WHERE "my_table"."mycolumn" = $1 LIMIT 1 LOCK IN SHARE MODE
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "LOCK" at character 74
```

It works on SQLite though.

Comment: You cannot use the `LOCK` statement for locking *rows*, only for locking *tables*.

Comment: According to the Rails docs, the lock statement is actually locking the selected rows: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to update some rows in a table, and I want to lock them so
>   other processes don't update them as well at the same time. But I'd
>   like other processes to read them.

This is guaranteed automatically. It looks like you are trying to solve non-existent problem :-)

Other processes don't update until first update is finished.

In postgres, reads are NEVER blocked by writes.

Comment: Is this really true? We're debugging issues with an `after_create` that does something like (simplified) `Foo.update_all(["current = (id = ?)", self.id])`. The issue is that it can set more than one record as current – our working theory is that it happens in two transactions that are allowed to run in parallel and where each doesn't see the other new record.

Comment: Can you present more detail about your situation (I assume it is not exactly same as David's)? Also, I am not sure what `lock(true)` does in RoR/ActiveRecord. What SQL they generate? (Hint: set `logging_collector` and `log_statements` in `postgresql.conf` and restart)

Comment: I should probably make a separate question for it – just happened to see your answer and wanted to make sure you were sure, because if you are, our hypothesis is wrong. But in brief then: items have 1-N listings (you relist the item because the old listing expired). Only the most recently created listing should be current=true. In `Listing.after_create`, it does `Listing.update_all(["current = (id = ?)", id], item_id: item_id)`. If you double-submit creating a new listing, two can become current.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about RoR, but for PostgreSQL, I don't think the SQL statement in your error message would work. Locks in PostgreSQL are generally done via:
SELECT * from [YOUR_TABLE] where [CONDITION] FOR UPDATE

See this page for more documentation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/explicit-locking.html

Comment: Correct. You want `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`. This doesn't block reads, only other writes.

Comment: From what I'm reading in the Posgres docs, when updating a row/some rows, the lock is automatically applied so no other updates are done. This does not seem to affect reads.

Comment: @David Yep, that's right. `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` is useful if you want to control the lock acquisition ordering, acquire extra locks elsewhere, or acquire locks early to avoid a deadlock, though.